# Estimote Beacon template app. Nearest Beacon: null, distance: -1.0

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, beacon, estimote

I downloaded the template app named *Proximity Content for a single beacon* from cloud.estimote and selected my beetroot location beacon in the setup. 
The app works in my Huawei Mate 8 mobile and is able to detect the beacon.
But, it doesn't work on my Lenovo TAB3 8 tablet and Moto e3 mobile. 
The Android monitor in Android Studio shows `D/NearestBeaconManager: Nearest beacon: null, distance: -1.0` On both the tablet and moto e3 mobile the android studio shows this line and beacons are not to be found. But, in huawei mate 8 the template app works perfectly well.
All the devices are Android VERSION 6.0

Comment: Is your location permission is enabled for the device where beacons not found?

Comment: Check if BLE support is available in the device programmatically and then invoke the functionality. Location should be turned on.

Comment: @Jaimin location services in the devices are enabled.

Comment: @Stallion How to check it programmatically?